# Swing JRadioButton autoselect after get focus

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup, focuslistener

I have three JRadioButtons in ButtonGroup. With keyboard navigation with TAB I can go through this JRadioButtons (change focus), with SPACE I can select JRadioButton with focus. Is it possible that with TAB will be changed not only focus but also state of JRadioButton?

Comment: @mKorbel it's on jdialog with just 3 radiobuttons and two buttons (ok, cancel)

Comment: but for JRadioButtons in the ButtonGroup is possible to select only one element (by default, I see there hack), maybe proper way for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a FocusListener to the radio button to select it once it gains focus.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip for other readers:

```
myRadioButton.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
        myRadioButton.setSelected(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
        myRadioButton.setSelected(true);
    }
});
```